# After upgrading Oracle JDBC driver, a Hibernate criteria query throws exception

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, oracle11g

I recently upgraded the JDBC driver for Oracle 11g from `ojdbc14.jar` to `ojdbc6.jar`.
However, the following criteria query does not work anymore now:

```
criteria = ...
criteria = criteria.createAlias("contract", "contract")
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.isNull("contract.dateend"))
    .add(Restrictions.gt("contract.dateend", new Date())));
```

which restricts the result to entities which are associated to contracts which are still running.

The following exception occurs:

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)
    at <<my method which creates the criteria query>>
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: year out of range.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DateCommonBinder.setOracleCYMD(OraclePreparedStatement.java:19241)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.TimestampBinder.bind(OraclePreparedStatement.java:19520)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2355)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3579)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    ... 101 more
```

As said before, it still works fine with the old driver. The corresponding database column has type `DATE` which is supposed to be mapped 
by Hibernate to `java.util.Date` by:

```
<property name="dateend">
    <column name="DATEEND" length="7" />
</property>
```

Do I have to change the Hibernate mapping for this column?

Thanks in advance,
Rainer.

Answer (score 2):

Found the reason for this behavior. There were both versions of the JDBC driver on the class path. I had only updated the lib in the Tomcat lib folder. However, there was still an old version in my `war` archive. This caused the error